# Why create script tag via Javascript, instead of using defer or async script tag attributes?

Tags: javascript, html, asynchronous, disqus, livefyre

Some Web applications (I'm thinking about Disqus and LiveFyre) create `<script>` tags via Javascript, and via Javascript specify that the new scripts be loaded asynchronously. Why do they create the tags via Javascript? Instead of simply doing:

```
<script src="..." async>
```

*An example:*

This is how Disqus instructs website owners to load comments:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var disqus_shortname = ...
    (function() {
        var s = document.createElement('script');
        s.type = 'text/javascript';
        s.async = true;
        s.src = '//' + disqus_shortname + '.disqus.com/embed.js';
        (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] ||
           document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(dsq);
    })();
</script>
```

And the `src = ...disqus.com/embed.js` address is simply a redirect to a static script on another Disqus server, apparently independent of the *disqus_shortname*.

Why not instead tell people to use this piece of code:

```
<script>
    var disqus_shortname = ...
</script>
<script src="http://direct-address-to-the-embed.js-script" async>
```

Or even simpler, just one line:

```
<script src="http://the_disqus_shortname.disqus.com/embed.js" async>
```

?

<sub>(P.S. I added one answer below. Please do add other answers too :-))</sub>

Answer (score 0):

I can think of one uncertain (no. 1) and two likely reasons (no. 2 and 3):

**[Edit]** But reasons 2 and 3 are moot points — Disqus could simply do this despite of my reasons 2 and 3:

```
<script src="http://the_disqus_shortname.disqus.com/embed.js" async>
```

**[/Editi]**

1. (Perhaps old browsers that doesn't understand the `async` attribute completely ignore the whole `<script ... async>` tag? Instead of ignoring only `async` and loading the script synchronously?)
2. Perhaps Disqus would like to be able to genereate the embedded script dynamically, or redirect to different scripts, depending on website settings (*although* it seems as if Disqus currently always redirects to the same `embed.js` script always). Without having users reconfigure their Disqus code.
3. Using a redirect allows Disqus to tell the browser to cache the-scripts-that-is-redirected-to for a long amount of time, but at the same time makes it possible to quickly redirect to another script. At the cost of 1 redirect per download / fetch-from-browser-cache. This was suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10098250/694469

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that Disqus (and other services) want to ensure that their scripts doesn't slow down loading of user sites *whenever you put their script* (probably many CMSes put scripts in a head element).

If you always put your scripts at the end of a body element then writing short version may be optimal:

```
    ...
    <script>var disqus_shortname = ...</script>
    <script src="//shortname.disqus.com/embed.js" async>
</body>
```

I'm not sure though!

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! I'm getting the impression that you're answering another question, namely "Why do they put the `<script>` in the `<body>` not the `<head>`? — Or are you suggesting that there is some difference performance wise between using a `<script src=...>` tag, or doing: `<script>... document.createElement('script'); ... s.src =...; ...</script>`?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit old but still relevant, the main reason we do it is because some tools, such as google-tag-manager, don't accept scripts with certain properties set on them.
e.g. if you try to set the refferer-policy to 'unsafe-url' then google tag manager will just ignore your request to add the `<script>` tag.